# Python Cannot search data in Facebook

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping

I want to search data in facebook by using [facebook_scraper](https://github.com/kevinzg/facebook-scraper) like this code

```
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
for post in get_posts('nintendo', cookies="cookies.json",  pages=10):
    print(post)
```

I try to search in another language like this.

```
get_posts('khách sạn', cookies="cookies.json",  pages=10)
```

It show output is empty. How to search another language using facebook_scraper?

Comment: You have accidentally posted this twice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76238520/python-cannot-search-data-in-facebook

Comment: Consider deleting this question as I have answered the other one. There is no need for duplicate questions and answers.